# could i use higher function on this?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, for-loop

this is a code that I want to know if I want to use in some other functions, such `ForEach`, `map`, `filter`, or `what else`?
is that possible?

```js
const val = 'Mike,Mike@mail.com,male'

const split = val.split(',')
console.log(split) //to check

const newObj = {}

newObj.name = split[0]
newObj.email = split[1]
newObj.gender = split[2]

console.log(newObj)
```

```js
const val2 = 'name:John,email:John@mail.com'

const split2 = val2.split(',')
 console.log(split2) //to check
const newObj2 = {}

  for(var i = 0; i < split2.length; i++) {
    var data = split2[i].split(':')
    newObj2[data[0]] = data[1]
  }

console.log(newObj2)
```

want to  make the code more clean and short

Comment: They are two different strings, what exactly is it you're trying to do? The same result with either string? But that can't be as gender is only in the first string. It's a little unclear to me.

Comment: i want to the same results / output @DarrenSweeney

Comment: Ok, but as I said, the strings are different in structure and content, so what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Best thing to do, fix the string so it is a valid JSON object and no need to transform it. That would be the best thing to do. Other than using reduce, there is not much improvement on the code.

Comment: I want to know the method to other codes to make that code have the same results @epascarello & DarrenSweeney

Comment: @ZrClassic We understand what you want but your first example and your second example have different input fields. They cannot have the same output.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const val = 'Mike,Mike@mail.com,male'

const [name, email, gender] = val.split(',')

console.log({name, email, gender})
```

```js
const val2 = 'name:John,email:John@mail.com'

const splitByColon = term => {
  const [key, value] = term.split(':')
  return {[key]: value}
}

console.log(
  val2
    .split(',')
    .reduce((acc, term) =>
      ({...acc, ...splitByColon(term)}), {})
)
```

Comment: You should explain what you are doing and mention browser support for these features.

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be

```js
const val = 'name:Mike,email:Mike@mail.com,gender:male'

const obj = {}
val.split(',')
   .map(prop => prop.split(':'))
   .forEach(([key, value]) => {
     obj[key] = value
   })

console.log(obj)
```